# How to delegate programmatically?

Tags: origination

I have successfully implemented an origination method and it is working. Nevertheless, when I try to set a  delegate to the originated address, it does nothing. I receive no errors at all from the Tezos node. But the operation hash points to nothing.

In the operations array, I am appending a reveal op (to reveal the originated address) and a delegation op.

The manager  address is: tz1S37hEZnNrAXfzuRYSjG9Qxq8VrwpWaukB and the originated address is KT1XFqZeHDPw4TmkjgCN5knsYvZYGj2r5c3F.

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Klassare, who kindly analysed my JSON, it worked. I was using the wrong FEEs values. This table might help many other developers:

[image]